# Access child elements in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Using Python's Selenium I got the first div element because I needed the onclick element.

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-user-frontpage')
# I got the onclick element
```

This part is working for me. But now I also want to have the `img` element starting from the code above. I don't want to use XPATH.

```
<div class="action-link card card-user-frontpage card-user-36405612 hover" onclick="window.location.href='/user/36405612/3';">
    <div class="card-block">
        <div class="userimage action-link pull-left placeholder" onclick="window.location.href='/user/36405612/3';">
            <img onclick="" src="blabla../user/170x170/male.jpg" class=" userimage-170x170 user-image" data-show-count="0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="">
```

Like accessing the child elements in Selenium. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the *`<img>`* element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-user-frontpage > div.card-block > div.userimage.action-link.pull-left.placeholder > img")
  ```
- With respect to the element you found:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'card-user-frontpage')
  # I got the onclick element
  my_element = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.card-block > div.userimage.action-link.pull-left.placeholder > img")
  ```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is that there are many `card-userfront-page` so that I want to start from mine if u know what I mean?

Comment: @hallowelt123 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, worked well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into Page Object model for automation. What it boils down to is that you have to tag each interactable element manually with a unique end-to-end tag e.g. `<Button data_e2e='account__editEmail_button_sendCode'>`, my logic is `page__context_tagType_name`.

Then i'd do something akin to this in the `account.page.js` file (this is using cypress, but logic is similar).

```
// extends from Page to use super.find (There's gotta be something similar in selenium)
class UpdateEmail extends Page {
  get ButtonSendVerificationCode()  { return super.find('account__editEmail_button_sendCode');}

  clickButtonSendVerificationCode() {
    this.ButtonSendVerificationCode.click();
  }
}
```

Then use this logic in your spec files any time you need to use the page file.

The `page.js` file:

```
module.exports = class Page {
  find(id) {
    return cy.get(`[data_e2e="${id}"]`);
  }

  open(path) {
    cy.visit(`${path}`);
  }
}
```